# WebApi 2 HttpPut, HttpDelete, HttpPost not working-HTTP Error 405.0 - Method Not Allowed

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api2

I couldn't access this method:

```
[HttpPut]
[Route("api/Order/Update/{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateList([FromBody]OrderViewModel order, [FromRoute]int id)
{

}
```

I get the error:

> HTTP Error 405.0 - Method Not Allowed

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem:

Solution is to uninstall WebDAV module.
Control Panel -> Programs and Features -> Turn Windows features on or off -> IIS -> World Wide Web Services -> Common HTTP Feature -> WebDAV Publishing.

Answer (score 1):

yes - that should do the job, however you could just disable webDav in web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
        <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
        <remove name="WebDAV" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

cheers